# I want to take numbers from a file and skip any string, after that i want to append every number inside one list. in python

Tags: python

so this is the file that I'm reading from
I just want to extract the numbers from the file and put it in a list without taking any string along.

```
Salem Al Rashed
1200
Sara Al Kandari
950
Ahmad Al Fadli
1550
```

and this is the codes that I wrote but didn't work

```
my_list = []
file = open("employees.txt","r")    

for lines in file:
    if lines == ""
    slicing = int[lines]
```

Comment: what should I so i can append only the integers from the file inside a list that's it and thnx for your concern i found the soultion

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
f = open("employees.txt","r")
employees = f.read().split("\n")
f.close()

nums = []
for e in employees:
    try:
        nums.append(int(e))
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(nums)
```

Have a look at this article for some insight into parsing files with python:
https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/